# Suppress opening a MATLAB figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

How can I prevent MATLAB from plotting an object and it's transformation? I am trying to rotate a surface and am using a transformation matrix to do it, but I don't want the surface to be plotted at any point, How can I stop it?

```
% Defines the input variables for the SC at the orbital point.
FoV = deg2rad(FoV);
dist = sqrt(xp^2 + yp^2 + zp^2);

xp = 168.820350140000;
yp = 22703.2636668300
zp = 40331.2908433900

% Generates a line from the orbit point to the centre of the Earth.
xl = linspace(0,xp);
yl = linspace(0,yp);
zl = linspace(0,zp);   

% Plots the orbits, orbit point, and Earth object onto the same plot.
plot3(xl,yl,zl);
hold on
scatter3(xp,yp,zp,100,'x','blue')

% Creates a cone for the FoV of the SC that targets the Earth's centre.
[x,y,z] = cylinder([dist*tan(FoV) 0],100);
h = surface(y,dist*z,x);
t = hgtransform('Parent',ax);
set(h,'Parent',t);
x_temp = get(h,'xdata');y_temp = get(h,'ydata');z_temp = get(h,'zdata'); % Duplicates data.

% Determines the coordinate rotations needed to align the cone with the
% orbit point and transforms the cone using object R.   
% This if loop calibrates the cone for the 4 quadrants of 2 tangents.
xa = atan(yp/xp);
za = atan(zp/sqrt(xp^2+yp^2));
if xp>0
   xa = xa-pi/2;
else
   xa = xa+pi/2;
end
R = makehgtform('zrotate',xa,'xrotate',za);
set(t,'Matrix',R);

% Performs the same numerical transformation of the duplicate data and
% creates a sew sets of coordinates that match the transformation.
for i = 1:101
    new_first_row(i,:) = (R * [x_temp(1,i);y_temp(1,i);z_temp(1,i);1])';
    new_second_row(i,:) = (R * [x_temp(2,i);y_temp(2,i);z_temp(2,i);1])';
end
xr = new_first_row(:,1)';       % Transformed x data.
xr(2,:) = new_second_row(:,1)';
yr = new_first_row(:,2)';       % Transformed y data.
yr(2,:) = new_second_row(:,2)';
zr = new_first_row(:,3)';       % Transformed z data.
zr(2,:) = new_second_row(:,3)';
```

I want `xr`, `yr`, and `zr` to be calculated, but don't want any plots to be created from this specific script. I later want to create a different plot using this data. If there are any other ways of doing this, please let me know.

Comment: You are creating the plots. You have codes that specifically and uniquely create plots. `surface`'s only job is to plot! It seems liek you are using the wrong tool for the job. What is the purpose of that section of the code? you can apply geometric transformations and other stuff to data, without the need of plotting.

Comment: I'm, very new to MATLAB so I'm not very familiar with the tools and how to use them. The aim of the code is to create a field of view cone, from a point, aimed towards the origin. I want the coordinates of the cone. I get them by making a cone of the correct dimensions along the x-axis and then rotating it to line up with the origin vector of the point.

Comment: You rotate a surface plot, not a cone. You make a plot, then take the plot, then rotate that plot, and extract its new location. You seem to have the XY problem. Your actual problem is how to create a cone and rotate it, not how to avoid plotting with your attempt of doing it.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'll post a new question.

Comment: Or [edit] this one

Comment: I rolled back the edit here, as it invalidated a current answer (being mine). Figure visibility has nothing to do with cone-cross section calculations, so please ask a new question about that. Only edit questions to clarify things, don't completely change a question, especially when invalidating existing answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Ander Biguri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59263893/suppress-matlab-plot-with-transform-matrix/59264142#comment104736099_59263893) already said, there are probably better ways than to cram a round peg into a square hole.
As to the question itself: [figure visibility](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1_sep_shared-Visible) is controlled through `figure('Visible', 'off')`, where `'on'` is obviously the default. Don't forget to close your figure though:

```
fig = figure('Visible', 'off'); % Create invisible figure with handle
h = surface(...); % Your plot
% (...) your other processing
close(fig); % Close figure to save RAM
```